# Is JPA2 CriteriaQuery with parameter thread safe to create query from?

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa-2.1

I want to have reusable `CriteriaQuery` similar to this:

```
    CriteriaBuilder b = cb();
    CriteriaQuery<MyClass> query = b.createQuery(MyClass.class);
    Root<MyClass> myClass= query.from(MyClass.class);
    where.add(b.equal(applicant.get(MyClass_.id),          b.parameter(Integer.class, "id")));
    query.where(where.toArray(new Predicate[where.size()]));
    return query;
```

Now in worker threads pool I want to perform following operation:

```
TypedQuery<MyClass > query = em.createQuery(myClassCriteria);
query.setParameter("id", id);
MyClass a = query.getSingleResult();
em.detach(a);
return a;
```

where `myClassCriteria` is `CriteriaQuery` from above.

is that a thread safe apporach? I suspect, that setting parameter on `query` can internally modify given `CriteriaQuery` making it non-tread-safe.

My suspicions came from the situation that occasionally app threw some SQL error saying that `parameter 2 is not set`. I dont even know what parameter 2 here is as I have only 1 paremeter in query, neverheless this makes me thing that resusing parametrized query in such way can be non-thread safe.

Error are rahter not reproducable on demand, so It is hard to confirm the cause.

My JPA provider is Hiberate

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

TypedQuery holds the parameter value and not CriteriaQuery. It should be not shared to other instance of typedQuery. I think it is thread safe. (Like named queries are threadsafe)

Check that id is always filled. 
Also check if this is the only one query that could cause this error or there is other query (with two parameters) being executed.

Comment: That is what I am thinking, but it looks otherwise - maybe a bug in Hibernate idk. Random error is gone since I used `ThreadLocal<CriteriaQuery>`.